# can't find why i'm facing this error in script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

```
# match PLEX_REMOTE_DYNDNS IPs against resolved IPs
matched_ips=( $(comm -12 < ( printf '%s\n' "${trusted_wan[@]}" | LC_ALL=C sort) <(printf '%s\n' "${resolved_ips[@]}" | LC_ALL=C sort)) )
```

---

Once I execute this, the next error faced

> syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: Pay attention to spaces. Just like letter case they are frequently important. And your error message suggests to look at your script near parentheses...

Comment: Why do you write a space after the first `<`?